# Invalid column data type "" when reindexing catalog_product_flat

Tags: magento2, reindex

I'm using Magento 2.3.3 and when I try to reindex, the category flat was not reindexed and shows an error like this: Invalid column data type ""

[image]

Every Answer in here sends me to this
[Invalid column data type when reindex Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/323535/invalid-column-data-type-when-reindex-magento-2)

but that didn't fix it for me, I tried adding

```
            case 'int unsigned':
                $columnType = 'int';
                break;
            case 'smallint unsigned':
                $columnType = 'smallint';
                break;
            case 'bigint unsigned':
                 $columnType = 'bigint';
                 break;
```

into getDdlTypeByColumnType function of "vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/Helper.php"
but that didn't work, any other Solutions?

[image]